in_app_purchase event stopped being reported on iOS
I noticed that we suddenly stopped receiving the in_app_purchase event for iOS devices since July 18th.
We continue seeing the event for Android device but for iOS we are not getting nothing in that event.
The other automatically collected events are working as expected.
I have a Flutter app integrated with the Flutter SDK, using the latest version of the packages.
I already created issues in the Flutter and iOS SDK and both send me to Firebase support but they are not contacting me. I saw an issue about StoreKit 2 but we are using StoreKit 1

In GA for Firebase, the in_app_purchase event is automatically collected when a user completes an in-app purchase that is processed by Google Play to App Store.
To ensure that in-app purchase data will flow from Google Play or App Store to GA for Firebase successfully and correctly, you can check the following:

Link your Firebase project to a Google Analytics 4 property
Make sure that your app is using the correct version of Analytics SDK

For this issue, your go-to people should be the Firebase support. They have the necessary tools to investigate the possible cause and help you resolve the issue.
